# Column name as computed string in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I have a result set in which I have to create column name like 
 'LastWeek (12th March - 18th March)'

First I have tried simple query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CONCAT('LastWeek (', DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 7 DAY),'%D %M'),' - ',DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 DAY),'%D %M'),')') From Mytable
```

but it fails
then i have tried simple sp

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `mydb`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test`(  
    )
BEGIN
    DECLARE lv_Duration VARCHAR(100);    
         SET @lv_Duration = CONCAT('LastWeek (', DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 7 DAY),'%D %M'),' - ',DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 DAY),'%D %M'),')'); 
    SELECT 'test' AS @lv_Duration;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

but it also fails. Please let me know if some how this is possible or not
Later I am utilizing my resultset via generic C# method

```
private string GetStoredProcedureWiseCustomResult(DataTable dt)
        {
            var str = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                str.Append(String.Format("[{0}] {1}", column.ColumnName, "\t\t"));
            }
            str.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {
                    str.Append(String.Format("[{0}] {1}", dr[column.ColumnName], "\t\t"));
                }
                str.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            }
            return str.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: You can't do that, field names are not strings and can't be manipulated as strings.  What you need to do is create an entirely new SQL statement each time.  See "Dynamic SQL".  Or, better still, just call it LastWeek and then present it as something different in your presentation layer.  It looks like you're trying to couple your SQL directly to your presentation, which is a big no-no.

Comment: Thanks MatBailie. I also preffered the later suggestion but my solution is a generic solution where we configure stored procedure and column name and it's data are outputted without any stored procedure wise processing.

Comment: This is a *very strange task*.  The data access layer should almost always know, *in advance*, the name of every column that is to appear in a resultset—after all, how else will it access and use them?  Fair enough if those names are dynamically generated *within that data access layer* (e.g. as it assembles the SQL): it can then retain its knowledge of such assigned aliases for use once the resultset is returned.  But generating the names at a lower level, such as in the RDBMS itself as you are attempting to do, is fraught with difficulties.

Comment: eggyal Actually i am validating some rule if I get the result set back it mean's my rule verified and have to do some messaging. for certain rules Now I have to concat the resultset as well.

Comment: That still doesn't explain you think it's necessary to generate a column name in the RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the query dynamically where you can specify the calculated name for you column. For example,

string query = " SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'LastWeek ("+ FirstDate +", "+ SecondDate +")' "+
" From Mytable ";

Now pass this query to stored procedure to get the output.

**OR**

By using below query you will get the Column name as per your need. You can update the **Convert** function use to get the name as per your need.

```
DECLARE @str1 NVARCHAR(MAX) 

SET @str1 = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS ''LastWeek ('+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),DATEADD(DD,-7,GetDate()),110) + ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GetDate(),110) + ')'' FROM MyTable'

exec(@str1)
```

Hoper this helps!

Comment: Dynamic sql is not an option for me